# Do Stormtroopers ever use the sights of their E-11 blaster rifles?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, weapon, stormtroopers

This is an E-11 blaster rifle:

[image: Blaster Rifle]

It was standard issue for stormtroopers and makes many, many appearances in various *Star Wars* works.

Recently, I noticed this:

[image: Circle]

These guns have sights. I can't recall ever seeing these sights used in any medium. Does anyone know if they ever had been used? It would seem that it would really help with the stormtroopers' aiming issues.

Comment: It's not that they don't use the sights. It's just that the sights are so incredibly **bad**!!!

Comment: Why could the scope not be patched up to a tactical display in the helmet? i.e., you could point the blaster anywhere, even behind you, and you could see what's lined up in the crosshairs? Seems plausible enough, in a sci-fi setting like Star Wars.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

During the Battle of Endor:

[image: Battle of Endor]

[image: Battle of Endor]

[image: Battle of Endor]

And of course, this guy shot Artoo.

[image: Battle of Endor]

---

I originally did not include this shot that hit Leia, because I feel it is ambiguous whether the scope is in use or not.

[image: Battle of Endor]

Comment: One of the few storm trooper blaster fatalities (against an android) and hits on a main character (Leia) involved the use of the site.  It's sad that it took them three episodes to master this technology.

Comment: @Hoytman I added a picture of that shot that hit Leia. I cannot tell whether the stormtrooper is using the scope or not.

Comment: It doesn't look like the shot that hit R2 was aimed through the scope either, honestly.

Answer (score 44):

[image]

This is from *Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope*.  In the video of this scene (0:14), we can clearly see this particular stormtrooper (circled in red) aim down the sight *and fire at Han*:

Comment: I agree with the other answer (which is incomplete); it doesn't look like the stormtrooper was actually looking down the sight.

Comment: @Null: It's a certain point of view. ;-)

Comment: @Praxis My point of view is from the first person. ;)

Comment: Was that in the original version too, or just the enhanced version?

Comment: @Hurkyl : Enhanced, I believe.

Comment: I love that shot of all those Stormtroopers just hanging around :,)

Answer (score 42):

Since you've asked for any medium, the most unambiguous way to confirm that stormtroopers used their sights is using a video game.

Here's a gif (taken from 2:14 of [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=AKNVoGwXNXI#t=134)) of a [cold weather assault stormtrooper (snowtrooper)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cold_weather_assault_Stormtrooper) using the sight on his E-11 to get headshots on Rebel soldiers at the Battle of Hoth (from [*Star Wars: Battlefront II*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars%3A_Battlefront_II)):

[image]

And here's a similar gif (taken from 32:40 of [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=VWSeWcvuHSA#t=1960)) from [DICE](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/EA_Digital_Illusions_CE)'s new [*Star Wars: Battlefront*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Battlefront) (which is largely [canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112442/31936)):

[image]

Notice that this snowtrooper's HUD is displaying a note that he's already killed fifteen Rebels while he kills his sixteenth. These snowtroopers prove that Imperial troops can be quite effective and deadly, contrary to certain naysayers!

We know these are snowtroopers because (a) snowtroopers formed the Imperial infantry at the [Battle of Hoth](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Hoth/Canon) and (b) a few seconds after the indicated time in the second clip we see the snowtrooper with his E-11:

[image]

As a bonus, both gifs show that the sight is a scope since there is some magnification when aiming down it.

Comment: Whoa, indeed a live example of the sights in use. I imagine this actually us a scope, not an optic, as it magnifies the target image when used. (Of course, this is Star Wars, so for all we know it might be a screen projecting an arbitrary image for the user -- which is a much more interesting/advanced use, which is the direction modern targetting systems are moving toward today anyway.)

Comment: @zxq9 I agree, both gifs indicate that it's a scope since there is some magnification.

Answer (score 23):

No. There is no canon explanation why helmeted soldiers with limited vision would be able to make use of a scope on a rifle they mostly hip fire anyway. There is one example of a stormtrooper raising their rifle to fire, but in this example it cannot be made out whether the stormtrooper is using their scope or merely raising their rifle to brace for recoil (maybe this explains why they are usually so inaccurate when firing from their hip?).

An out of universe answer would be the reason they added the scopes to the E-11 Blaster Rifle was to make it better replicate existing earth weapons, even though the Blaster rifles in the star wars universe are rarely used for long distance pitched assaults, but more frequently for corridor shootouts.

The analysis I have made upon the aforementioned scene where a stormtrooper appears to raise their weapon is as follows:

- You can clearly see from the diagram below the orientation of the gun and the stormtroopers visor do not line up
- The stormtroopers helmet eye-holes do not line up to the scope

[image]

A better explained theory as to what the stormtrooper is doing is as follows:

- The stormtrooper, seeing Han has raised his weapon in order to improve accuracy by reducing the recoil on his blaster.

Comment: Why was this answer nominated for deletion?  It's really quite good!

Comment: I'm not sure I buy this analysis.  I can't "clearly" see this.  His stance is consistent with aiming (otherwise he would adopt a stance more like the others) and also we can't infer the direction of his eyes from his mask.

Comment: @TangerinesonTatooine, it's true that you can't tell the direction of his gaze. You *can* however tell that he isn't using his sight for one simple reason: His eyes are not in line with the sight at all. They are far too high. He may be getting ready to use the sight, but he certainly is not using it now.

Comment: Also, it'd be hard to use the sight at all with these helmets. The sight is close to the gun body; it would be quite hard to use with a bulky helmet.

Comment: I have edited my question to better sum up my thoughts, is this still not an answer to the question?

Comment: @JustAnotherDotNetDev : Thanks for editing your answer.  This is definitely an answer now. :-)

Comment: Thank you for helping me improve the quality of this post :^)

Comment: @JustAnotherDotNetDev : No worries --- and a belated welcome to SFF:SE, by the way. (I noticed that you've only been a member for a couple of months.)

Comment: long time reader, first time poster, thanks

Comment: Clearly he raised the weapon so that he wouldn't fire into the foreground trooper's rife.

Comment: Do blasters (being energy weapons) have recoil?

Answer (score 6):

Out of universe, and not an answer, but interesting and too much for a comment...

The E-11 blaster prop is a modified [Sterling sub-machine gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterling_submachine_gun). The scope is not a rifle scope, but a 1.44x scope from a [Sherman tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_Sherman)!

An inappropriate scope, plus the helmet, probably made it very difficult for the actors to see through.

[M40 scope](http://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/real-m40-tank-scope-11-star-wars-1727024574)

[image: M40 scope]

[M38 scope](http://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/ww-ii-m38-telescope-1942-sherman-tank-azimuth).

[image: M38 scope]